# Where to define reusable subschemas in OpenAPI 3?

Tags: openapi

I'm working on OpenAPI 3 document. I have schema called `CustomerInfo:` that has property `Address`. One of the properties of `Address` is enum called `State`. How do I make `State` a reusable property that can be referenced in other parts of `CustomerInfo` ?

```
components:
  schemas:
   CustomerInfo:
    type: object
    properties:
      Address:
        type: object
        description: Contains the street, city, zip, and state associated with an address.
        properties:
          State:
            $ref: ''
        required:
          - Street1
          - State
```

I was thinking about defining a `State` under `definitions:` within `CustomerInfo`, but https://editor.swagger.io/ is throwing exception :

```
components:
  schemas:
   CustomerInfo:
    type: object
    properties:
      Address:
        type: object
        description: Contains the street, city, zip, and state associated with an address.
        properties:
          State:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/CustomerInfo/definitions/State'
        required:
          - Street1
          - State
    definitions:
      State: ....
```

Comment: What do you mean, "subschemas"? AFAIK you cannot scope an OAS schema to be valid only inside another OAS schema.

Comment: by the way, consider accepting the state information based on an ISO standard. Then you don't have to update that enum. And for clarity, you might want to rename to "country" to avoid ambiguities ("state" as in Florida, Texas, ... versus as in France, Italy, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the schema of `State` under `components/schemas` and it can be referenced.

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    CustomerInfo:
      type: object
      properties:
        Address:
          type: object
          description: Contains the street, city, zip, and state associated with an address.
          properties:
            State:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/State'
          required:
          - State
    State:
      type: string
      enum:
        - Alabama
        - Alaska
        - Arizona
```